# Only run useSWR once on page load with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, laravel-cashier

Im trying to create a custom stripe payment form in NextJS and im having a little trouble.

I need to create a payment intent, this means sending a request to my API and returning a secret key .... I am using `useSWR` and axios, but im finding that the way i have it setup, it keeps requesting another client secret from the API, so I only want to run the api call once when the page loads, but im not sure how to do it with useSWR and axios .. This is what i have;

```
const BillingPage = () => {
    const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

    const {data: intent, error, mutate} = useSWR('/api/stripe-intent', () => 
        axios.get('/api/stripe-intent')
            .then(response => response.data)
    )

    if (! intent) {
        return (<LoadPageComponent />)
    }

    const options = {
        clientSecret: intent?.client_secret,
    }

    return (
        <>
            <p>Payment form here</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

Is there any way to only run the call once?

Answer (score 0):

To disable automatic revalidation you can use `useSWRImmutable`.

You can read more about it [in the docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#disable-automatic-revalidations).